# How to work with custom fields using a template

Tags: xml, rest, templates, docusignapi, custom-fields

I've been working with the API and one issue materialized in the moment I tried to use custom fields to pass information to an envelope that can help me to track it back.
From what I understood they're some sort of metadata, visible or not, that when created are associated with every template we have created and stored (serverTemplates).
I've been able to create my template using two distinct documents, and I've added customize tabs using the API when sending the envelope.
Unfortunately, what I cannot get is the custom fields.
I've created them following this:https://www.docusign.co.uk/support/classic/documentation/cdse-admin-guide/account-admin/envelope-custom-fields
but no way I can override the value from the API.
Here's part of the XML call I've used:

```
body = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
        "<accountId>" + accountId + "</accountId>" +
        "<status>sent</status>" +    
        "<emailSubject>DocuSign API Call - Signature request from template</emailSubject>" +

        "<customFields>" + 
        "<textCustomFields>" +
            "<textCustomField>" +
                "<fieldId>1</fieldId>" +
                "<name>agreement_id</name>" +
                "<required>true</required>" +
                "<show>true</show>" +
                "<value>" + agreementId + "</value>" +
            "</textCustomField>" +
            "<textCustomField>" +
                "<fieldId>2</fieldId>" +                                            
                "<name>party_name</name>" +
                "<required>true</required>" +
                "<show>true</show>" +
                "<value>" + partyName + "</value>" +
            "</textCustomField>" +
        "</textCustomFields>" + 
        "</customFields>" +

        "<compositeTemplates>" +
           "<compositeTemplate>" +
              "<serverTemplates>" +
                 "<serverTemplate>" +
                    "<sequence>1</sequence>" +
                    "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
                 "</serverTemplate>" +
              "</serverTemplates>" +
              "<inlineTemplates>" +
                 "<inlineTemplate>" +
                    "<sequence>2</sequence>" +
                     "<recipients>" +
                        "<signers>" +
                            "<signer>" +
                               "<email>" + email + "</email>" +
                               "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                               "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
                               "<roleName>" + roleName + "</roleName>" +                                     


                               "<tabs>" + 
                                   "<textTabs>" + 
                                       "<text>" +
                                           "<tabLabel>agreement_id</tabLabel>" +
                                           "<value>" + agreementId + "</value>" +
                                           "<xPosition>220</xPosition>" +
                                           "<yPosition>348</yPosition>" +
                                           "<documentId>2</documentId>" +
                                           "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                                       "</text> " +

                                       "<text>" +
                                           "<tabLabel>party_name</tabLabel>" +
                                           "<value>" + partyName + "</value>" +
                                           "<xPosition>130</xPosition>" +
                                           "<yPosition>142</yPosition>" +
                                           "<documentId>2</documentId>" +
                                           "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                                       "</text> " +
                                   "</textTabs> " +
                               "</tabs>" + 

                            "</signer>" +
                        "</signers>" +                       
                     "</recipients>" +

                 "</inlineTemplate>" +
              "</inlineTemplates>" +
           "</compositeTemplate>" +
        "</compositeTemplates>" +           
        "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Can someone advise please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the ask? Are you trying to use the API to access the envelope custom fields (ECF's)?  I do know that if you have a template that have ECF's defined on it, or even on the account level, if you specify any ECF's in the API call for that envelope then only the ECF's specified in the API take effect. It's like the ECF's on the template/account level never existed, so the API trumps all in this case.

Comment: Hi Luis, you got the point. I'm trying to access the ECFs using the API. I've defined them using "agreement_id" and "party_name" as names, "Required" ticked and "text" type. In the code I've provided above I'm trying to access them and insert a customize value that I'll use to track this envelope back. Let me know if it's still not clear, and thanks for your help.

Comment: In addition, I should mention that the ECFs are correctly created and used by the template because if I create and send an envelope using the DocuSign UI all the information that I get back is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the composite template form it seems you must define the custom fields within the inline template.  Using the below request I defined three fields.  One is at the envelopeInformation level and is not reflected in the DocuSign system.  I defined two more in the inlineTemplate.  One that is configured at the account level (in my Preferences) and one that is not.  After creating the envelope, both are displayed in the UI (The UI properly honors the "show" flag on the newly created field).

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>
  <status>sent</status>
  <customFields>
    <textCustomFields>
      <textCustomField>
        <fieldId>1</fieldId>
        <name>Crazy Cool Custom Field Number 3</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <show>true</show>
        <value>67890</value>
      </textCustomField>
    </textCustomFields>
  </customFields>
  <compositeTemplates>
    <compositeTemplate>
      <serverTemplates>
        <serverTemplate>
          <sequence>1</sequence>
          <templateId>A32AA85C-EE69-4ABB-BE67-3B98A9FDC901</templateId>
        </serverTemplate>
      </serverTemplates>
      <inlineTemplates>
        <inlineTemplate>
          <customFields>
            <textCustomFields>
              <textCustomField>
                <fieldId>1</fieldId>
                <name>agreement_id</name>
                <required>true</required>
                <show>true</show>
                <value>12345</value>
              </textCustomField>
              <textCustomField>
                <fieldId>1</fieldId>
                <name>Crazy Custom Inline Field</name>
                <required>true</required>
                <show>true</show>
                <value>54321</value>
              </textCustomField>
            </textCustomFields>
          </customFields>
          <sequence>2</sequence>
          <recipients>
            <signers>
              <signer>
                <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                <email>me@u.them</email>
                <name>Bob Jones</name>
                <roleName>Signer1</roleName>
                <tabs>
                  <textTabs>
                    <text>
                      <tabLabel>NDACompany</tabLabel>
                      <value>12345</value>
                      <xPosition>100</xPosition>
                      <yPosition>100</yPosition>
                      <documentId>1</documentId>
                      <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                    </text>
                  </textTabs>
                </tabs>
              </signer>
            </signers>
          </recipients>
        </inlineTemplate>
      </inlineTemplates>
    </compositeTemplate>
  </compositeTemplates>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: thanks Jeff, it works now! I was definitely using the wrong level definition for those ECFs.